# iOS can't moving UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

```
NSLog(@"Before: %f",_inputView.frame.origin.y);
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
    [_inputView setFrame: CGRectMake(_inputView.frame.origin.x, 0, _inputView.frame.size.width, _inputView.frame.size.height)];
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    NSLog(@"After: %f",_inputView.frame.origin.y);
}];
```

I use this code to move my UIView but it doesn't move.
(Log -> Before: 520.00 After: 520.00)

Comment: Are you using auto layout or constraints on the view?

Comment: CGRectMake(_inputView.frame.origin.x, 0, _inputView.frame.size.width, _inputView.frame.size.height)  change the value of y =0 to some other value or replace like this value CGRectMake(_inputView.frame.origin.x+100, 0, _inputView.frame.size.width, _inputView.frame.size.height)

Comment: Yeah its happened, because you set your previous frame. You have to change x, y position to move. You set y value 0 to your target point, means your view is constant in same point.

Comment: I use auto layout. I changed y to difference value already.

Comment: I try _inputView.frame.size.y-100 already. I can't

Comment: you are changing the frame value.. Thats not correct approach.. If u r using auto layout then you should change your constraints..

Comment: Do you have some example to change constraint variable.Now I use button space to...

Comment: Thank you. I can already